# Selecting value in Combobox from cookie

Tags: cookies, extjs, combobox

Fellow programmers!

I want to do the following: In a screen users can select values in Comboboxes. These values are stored in a cookie so they can be restored when they visit the same page later in the session. The cookies work find, good job for ExtJs. The Comboboxes are server-bound and will retrieve their records upon opening them. That means that, upon restoring the cookie values, the required record may not be present. Retrieving the records from the server is no solution since the Comboboxes are paged and it would be a lot of hassle to figure exactly which page I must load.

I tried the following solution:

```
if(cookie.cobblerContactId != null) {
        var recDef = Ext.data.Record.create([
            {name: 'Id', type: 'int'},
            {name: 'Achternaam', type: 'string'}
        ]);
        var rec = new recDef({
            Id: cookie.cobblerContactId,
            Achternaam: cookie.CobblerContactName
        });           
        behandelaarStore.add(rec);
        behandelaarCombo.setValue(cookie.cobblerContactId);
        behandelaarCombo.render();
        //editForm.render();
    }
```

As you can see, I artificially create the record, add it to the datastore and select it. Problem is that the Combobox doesn't display the correct value, it appears unselected. Upon opening it will retrieve the first page of 25 records from the server. I have also tried the - commented out - editForm.render() but that also did not work. Writing text directly in the Combobox (cookie.CobblerContactName) did not work, I tried selectText() but that seems to be something different. If I just use selectValue() it displays the Id, not the text since the datastore does not have a record yet with that Id.

I've been trying the better parts of two days but can't get it to work. Does anybody have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `forceSelection: false` and then you can set text which is not part of the list.

Comment: forceSelection doesn't seem to have been the problem. As soon as my 8 hours have expired I can post the answer to this question, i.e. the code which got it actually running.

Answer (score 0):

The forceSelection doesn't seem to have anything to do with it since I add a genuine new record to the datastore which is subsequently selected. The displayed text, therefore, corresponds to an actual record. I got it working by now.

```
function getCookie() {
    if(Ext.util.Cookies.get('ticketIndexFilter') == null)
        return;
    var filterSet = Ext.ComponentMgr.get('additionalFilterSet');    
    var cookie = Ext.decode(Ext.util.Cookies.get('ticketIndexFilter'));
    txtNummer.setValue(cookie.TicketNr);
    if(cookie.datumVan != null && cookie.datumVan != ""){
        datVan.setValue(cookie.datumVan.substr(0, 10));
        filterSet.expand();
    }
    if(cookie.datumTm != null && cookie.datumTm != ""){
        datTm.setValue(cookie.datumTm.substr(0, 10));
        filterSet.expand();
    }
    if(cookie.relationId != null && cookie.relationId != "") {
        var recDef = Ext.data.Record.create([
            {name: 'Id', type: 'int'},
            {name: 'Name', type: 'string'}
        ]);
        var rec = new recDef({
            Id: cookie.relationId,
            Name: cookie.relationName
        }, cookie.relationId);           
        relatieStore.add(rec);
        relatieCombo.setValue(cookie.relationId);
    }
    if(cookie.cobblerContactId != null && cookie.cobblerContactId != "") {
        var recDef = Ext.data.Record.create([
            {name: 'Id', type: 'int'},
            {name: 'Achternaam', type: 'string'}
        ]);
        var rec = new recDef({
            Id: cookie.cobblerContactId,
            Achternaam: cookie.cobblerContactName
        }, cookie.cobblerContactId);           
        behandelaarStore.add(rec);
        behandelaarCombo.setValue(cookie.cobblerContactId);
        filterSet.expand();
    }
    if(cookie.statusId != null && cookie.statusId != "") {
        var recDef = Ext.data.Record.create([
            {name: 'Id', type: 'int'},
            {name: 'Naam', type: 'string'}
        ]);
        var rec = new recDef({
            Id: cookie.statusId,
            Naam: cookie.statusName
        }, cookie.statusId);           
        statusStore.add(rec);
        statusCombo.setValue(cookie.statusId);
        filterSet.expand();
    }
    if(cookie.priorityId != null && cookie.priorityId != "") {
        var recDef = Ext.data.Record.create([
            {name: 'Id', type: 'int'},
            {name: 'Naam', type: 'string'}
        ]);
        var rec = new recDef({
            Id: cookie.priorityId,
            Naam: cookie.priorityName
        }, cookie.priorityId);           
        prioriteitStore.add(rec);
        prioriteitCombo.setValue(cookie.priorityId);
        filterSet.expand();
    }
    if(cookie.relationContactId != null && cookie.relationContactId != "") {
        var recDef = Ext.data.Record.create([
            {name: 'Id', type: 'int'},
            {name: 'Achternaam', type: 'string'}
        ]);
        var rec = new recDef({
            Id: cookie.relationContactId,
            Achternaam: cookie.relationContactName
        }, cookie.relationContactId);           
        contactStore.add(rec);
        contactCombo.setValue(cookie.relationContactId);
        filterSet.expand();
    }
    if(cookie.categoryId != null && cookie.categoryId != "") {
        var recDef = Ext.data.Record.create([
            {name: 'Id', type: 'int'},
            {name: 'Naam', type: 'string'}
        ]);
        var rec = new recDef({
            Id: cookie.categoryId,
            Naam: cookie.categoryName
        }, cookie.categoryId);           
        categorieStore.add(rec);
        categorieCombo.setValue(cookie.categoryId);
        filterSet.expand();
    }
    //finally, an easy one
    opgelostBox.setValue(cookie.finalized);
}

function setCookie(){
    var filterPresets = {
        TicketNr: txtNummer.getValue(),
        datumVan: datVan.getValue(),
        datumTm: datTm.getValue(),
        relationId: relatieCombo.getValue(),
        relationName: relatieCombo.getValue() == "" ? null : relatieStore.getById(relatieCombo.getValue()).get('Name'),
        cobblerContactId: behandelaarCombo.getValue(),
        cobblerContactName: behandelaarCombo.getValue() == "" ? null : behandelaarStore.getById(behandelaarCombo.getValue()).get('Achternaam'),
        statusId: statusCombo.getValue(), 
        statusName: statusCombo.getValue() == "" ? null : statusStore.getById(statusCombo.getValue()).get('Naam'),
        priorityId: prioriteitCombo.getValue(),
        priorityName: prioriteitCombo.getValue() == "" ? null : prioriteitStore.getById(prioriteitCombo.getValue()).get('Naam'),
        relationContactId: contactCombo.getValue(),
        relationContactName: contactCombo.getValue() == "" ? null : contactStore.getById(contactCombo.getValue()).get('Achternaam'),
        categoryId: categorieCombo.getValue(),
        categoryName: categorieCombo.getValue() == "" ? null : categorieStore.getById(categorieCombo.getValue()).get('Naam'),
        finalized: opgelostBox.getValue()            
    };
    Ext.util.Cookies.set('ticketIndexFilter', Ext.encode(filterPresets));        
}
```

setCookie is called when the user presses the search button. getCookie is called in Ext.OnReady to preset the controls. It took me almost 10 hours to figure, so I thought I'd share.

The first post contained an error: *cookie.CobblerContactName* instead of *cookie.cobblerContactName*